# VBA cells are not highlighted

Tags: vba, excel

Its a protected worksheet/workbook and I have a code that will throw a prompt for the user, whether to edit the sheet or not. Cells are editable, but the problem is cells are not getting highlighted with border. So its difficult for the user to know which cells is he working on.

I have 2 sheets here, Corefiller and Ad-filler, if dropdown on corefiller sheet is "No". User gets a prompt when he selects the sheet, he clicks ok to edit the sheet or cancel if he doesnt want to edit.

**Code on Sheet "Ad-filler"**

```
Option Explicit

Private mMessageDisplayed As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Carry
End Sub
```

**Code on a module.**

```
Public Sub Carry()
    If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents And Not mMessageDisplayed Then
            mMessageDisplayed = True
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Corefiller").Range("E29") = "NO" Then
            If MsgBox("Click OK to include Filler for this request", vbOKCancel + vbInformation) = vbOK Then
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Corefiller").Range("E29") = "YES"
                With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ad-filler")
                    .Range("E13:E14").Locked = False
                End With
            Else
                 With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ad-filler")
                    .Range("E13:E14").Locked = True
                End With
            End If
        Else
        Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    End Sub
```

Whats wrong in my code? why the cell is not highlighted. If i try to use protect/unprotect in the code, cells on the first sheet (Corefiller) will not be highlighted and I have to click on other sheets and come back to get the cell highlighted.

[image]

Comment: You have no lines of code that apply borders to any cell(s).

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I meant the usual border we get when we click on cell, attached screenshot above..

Comment: You also have no code to **Select** any cells *(which would apply the border)*

Comment: @sady this sounds like a XL bug. Have you tried to restart? (I am not joking)

Comment: @Vityata Yes, I did. I tried closing/re-opening the excel sheet.

Comment: @sady by restart I meant a reboot of the machine.

Comment: @Vityata Certainly, I have been try to figure this out from couple of days and yes, I have restarted machine and tried but with no effect.

Comment: Did not know it was a couple of days issue, simply I have never experienced something similar...

Comment: @Vityata Yes, I did experience it too. Well, not able to figure out the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Which cell should be selected?

Answer (score 0):

Can you restart, implement this and check whether the problem still exists:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

End Sub
```

Comment: Using above code. Yes, cell wil be highlighted to red color but unfortunately will not solve my problem. As my intention is not to add a color to cell.

Comment: I know, I just thought that the SelectionChange event was blocked somehow.